# Unsuccessfully comparing player input and computer input Mastermind

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make Mastermind in C#. Everything is going okay except for comparing the code of the player to the code of the computer. I use numbers instead of colors and I put them in an array. These arrays will be compared. But the problem is that when one number (of the code) of the player corresponds with multiple numbers of the computer, it returns too many pins. I tried using a boolean that prevents going in the loop again when there are corresponding numbers, this unfortunately does not work and I can't seem to figure out why.

```cs
// I am trying to use this boolean to prevent getting more than one
// white pin for a single number, however this does not work yet
bool alreadyOcurredNumber = false;
for(int i = 0; i < codeOfPlayer.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < codeOfOpponent.Length; j++)
    {
        if (alreadyOcurredNumber == false)
            Console.WriteLine("boven " + alreadyOcurredNumber);
        {

            //this if looks for corresponding 'colors' that are also at the same index
            if ((codeOfOpponent[i] == codeOfPlayer[j]) && (i == j))
            {
                rightGuessRightIndex++;
                alreadyOcurredNumber = true;
            }
            //this if-statement looks if 'colors' correspond, regardless of the index
            else if ((codeOfOpponent[i] == codeOfPlayer[j]))
            {
                rightGuessWrongIndex++;
                alreadyOcurredNumber = true;
            }
        }
    }
    alreadyOcurredNumber = false;
}
```

Here is the whole program

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Mastermind
{
    class Program
    {
        public int[] createCodetoBreak(int[] inputArray) //Creating the code for the player to guess
        {
            int[] codeToGuess = new int[4];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < codeToGuess.Length; i++) 
            {
                codeToGuess[i] = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            }
            return codeToGuess;
        }

        public int[] createCodeOfPlayer(int[] codeOfPlayer) //creating the player's code with validation
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < codeOfPlayer.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Choose 4 of the next numbers! [1/2/3/4/5/6]");
                int playerInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (playerInput)
                {
                    case 1:
                        codeOfPlayer[i] = playerInput;
                        i++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        codeOfPlayer[i] = playerInput;
                        i++;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        codeOfPlayer[i] = playerInput;
                        i++;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        codeOfPlayer[i] = playerInput;
                        i++;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        codeOfPlayer[i] = playerInput;
                        i++;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        codeOfPlayer[i] = playerInput;
                        i++;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Voer ff wat normaals in man");
                        break;
                }
            }

            return codeOfPlayer;
        }




        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] codeOfPlayer = new int[4];
            int[] codeOfOpponent = new int[4];
            int amountOfTurns = 0;
            int rightGuessWrongIndex = 0;
            int rightGuessRightIndex = 0;
            //int wrongGuessWrongIndex = 0;

            Program mastermind = new Program();
            codeOfOpponent = mastermind.createCodetoBreak(codeOfOpponent);
            codeOfPlayer = mastermind.createCodeOfPlayer(codeOfPlayer);

            Console.WriteLine("The player's code is");
            for (int i = 0; i < codeOfPlayer.Length; i++)
                Console.Write(codeOfPlayer[i]);

            Console.WriteLine("\nThe opponent's code is");
            for (int i = 0; i < codeOfOpponent.Length; i++)
                Console.Write(codeOfOpponent[i]);
            Console.WriteLine('\n');

            bool alreadyOcurredNumber = false;

            //bepalen van de witte en zwarte/rode pinnetjes
            for(int i = 0; i < codeOfPlayer.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < codeOfOpponent.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (alreadyOcurredNumber == false)
                        Console.WriteLine("boven " + alreadyOcurredNumber);
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(alreadyOcurredNumber);
                        if ((codeOfOpponent[i] == codeOfPlayer[j]) && (i == j))
                        {
                            rightGuessRightIndex++;
                            alreadyOcurredNumber = true;
                        }
                        else if ((codeOfOpponent[i] == codeOfPlayer[j]))
                        {
                            rightGuessWrongIndex++;
                            alreadyOcurredNumber = true;
                            Console.WriteLine(alreadyOcurredNumber);
                        }
                    }
                }
                alreadyOcurredNumber = false;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Right number and right place: {0}", rightGuessRightIndex);
            Console.WriteLine("Right number and wrong place: {0}", rightGuessWrongIndex);
            //Console.WriteLine(wrongGuessWrongIndex);

            if (codeOfPlayer.SequenceEqual(codeOfOpponent) && amountOfTurns < 20)
                Console.WriteLine("You're right!"); 
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n Try again! ");
                amountOfTurns++;
            }




            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

There are some pieces of drafts in the code, please don't mind those. It's just for giving context.

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code? It's difficult to understand the problem from this snippet.